# Need help in SqlLite3 wasm

Tags: sqlite, local-storage

I need help with sqLite3 wasm.
I was previously used websql in my application but now it is deprecated so I am trying to use sqLite3 wasm.
Is there any way to create a sqlite file from the data stored in browser.
I have written this code to initialize db.

window.sqlite3InitModule().then(function (sqlite3) {

```
// The module is now loaded and the sqlite3 namespace

// object was passed to this function.

sqlite = sqlite3;

oo = sqlite.oo1;

db = new oo.JsStorageDb('local');
```

});

It is saving data in local storage so I want convert that data into sqlite file.

Comment: can you write the websql to a vb.net or C# project also what IDE are you using Visual Studio OR write the websql to a text file and convert that text to data for the sqlite file